# Increase the track length of SwitchCompat

Tags: android, android-appcompat, material-design

I am having a main on/off switch for my service at the top. I would like this switch to be big and visible.
If I change the textOn attribute to be longer, it is somewhat doing what I want, but I want that to happen with a shorter textOn string length.
I tried changing thumbTextPadding and switchMinWidth and both of them didn't increase the size of the switch.
How do I change the size of SwitchCompat object?
Currently my switch object is as below :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                android:id="@+id/start_service"
                style="@style/SwitchStyleCompat"
                android:text="@string/start_service_title"
                app:showText="true" />

<style name="SwitchStyleCompat">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">@dimen/heading_top_margin</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/heading_bottom_margin</item>
    <item name="track">@drawable/abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha</item>
    <item name="switchTextAppearance">@style/SwitchTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="android:thumb">@drawable/abc_switch_thumb_material</item>
    <item name="android:textOn">@string/switch_on</item>
    <item name="android:textOff">@string/switch_off</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentLeft">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentTop">true</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:checked">false</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/SwitchTextFont</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_heading_color</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|start</item>
    <item name="android:thumbTextPadding">25dp</item>
    <item name="android:switchMinWidth">56dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you have two options here :

1) Try changing the track drawable to something that is longer and you will obtain the result that you are looking for.
2) Pad the text with spaces so that the switchcompat will grow longer but visually you won't be able to tell the difference in the text.

Answer (score 20):

You can increase the track length by using the material attribute `app:switchMinWidth="70dp"`